# How to do DNS outside of VPN in Android VPN app

Tags: android, dns, vpn, httpsurlconnection, android-vpn-service

My Android app uses the `VpnService` API. The app makes some connections, starts a `VpnService` and shuttles data to-and-fro. Fairly normal.

While the `VpnService` is active, under particular circumstances I need to make an `HttpsURLConnection` to a remote server, and I need to do it *outside of the VPN*.

I can use `HttpsURLConnection.SetSSLSocketFactory()` with an appropriate `SSLSocketFactory` which protects the underlying socket from the VPN -- but the DNS lookup (performed internally to the `HttpsURLConnection`) goes through the VPN.

Is there a way to protect the DNS lookup (which boils down to a call by okhttp to `InetAddress.getAllByName()`) from the VPN?